# CSS Deciphering Background shorthand

Tags: css, background

I need a little help with breaking down someone's shorthand to longhand.

Here's what I've been given:

```
background: url("img.png") repeat scroll 0 0%, -moz-linear-gradient(#4E4E4E, #1C1C1C) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

I've gotten this far:

```
background-image:url('jAGNPCMaDe9LJ5wqwVhLimg.png');
```

But the rest is definitely greek to me.
I'm curious about the -moz-linear-gradent().  Is this something all browsers recognize? And I'm guessing the colors in the parenthesis must apply a gradient effect (deducing from -moz-linear-gradient)
And what does "repeat scroll 0 0%" do?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

here's your longhand:

```
#element{
  background-image:url(img.png);
  background-repeat:repeat;
  background-attachment:scroll;
  background-position:0 0;
  background-color:transparent
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(#4E4E4E, #1C1C1C);
}
```

The -moz-linear-gradient only works in Mozilla. That is why it is pre-fixed with -moz-. As you guessed right it makes a linear gradient as background, instead of the picture. But only in Mozilla, all other browsers use the background rules. The options of the gradient don't need to be repeated, because they are the same as for every other browser.

Comment: You seem to only have broken down only one half of it, and left the other half alone (and in fact, hanging by itself). This is a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, because it is exactly the same like the options for every other browser. But I have edited it and got rid of it completely, because the gradient options have been only a repeat of the before existing background options.

Comment: It's still wrong... the positions aren't identical and the layers aren't split into separate properties. See my answer for the correct way to break it down.

Comment: Please research before you try to educate me and downvote for something that is not true. I can set seperate layers in a single shorthand, but I don't need to. And the question was for a longhand and not another shorthand. Perhaps I should downvote your answer for not answering the question.

Comment: The question is asking for a longhand, but you've broken it down wrongly. My point is that breaking it down into `background-image: url(); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient();` is **not** the same as `background-image: url(), -moz-linear-gradient();`

Answer (score 3):

As [cimmanon has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476472/css-deciphering-background-shorthand/12476538#12476538), you're actually looking at two backgrounds combined into a single `background` shorthand declaration. The comma separates the two layers. This combination of multiple backgrounds is [new to CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering). So, you have two distinct background layers in shorthand notation:

```
url("img.png") repeat scroll 0 0%
-moz-linear-gradient(#4E4E4E, #1C1C1C) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent
```

And each expands to its own set of values.

The correct longhand expansion of your code is this:

```
background-image: url("img.png"), -moz-linear-gradient(#4E4E4E, #1C1C1C);
background-repeat: repeat, repeat;
background-attachment: scroll, scroll;
background-position: 0 0%, 0 0;
background-color: transparent;
```

Notice that, again, commas are used to separate multiple background layers. There is only one `background-color` because you cannot have multiple background colors.

Also as mentioned, the `-moz-` prefix is Mozilla's vendor extension used for its experimental implementation of [linear gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient). However, unless your `background` declaration is repeated for all other applicable vendor extensions, your code will only work in Mozilla browsers and no other browser because of the vendor extension.

Note also that if you use the longhand code above instead of the shorthand, unsupporting browsers will *only* ignore the `background-image` declaration and apply everything else, unlike the shorthand which unsupporting browsers will ignore *completely*.

Answer (score 2):

You're actually looking at multiple backgrounds there.  The comma is the separator.

```
url("img.png") repeat scroll 0 0% /* on top */
-moz-linear-gradient(#4E4E4E, #1C1C1C) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent /* on bottom */
```

The gradient is taking the spot of the background image.  The rest should be easy to figure out by reading up on the `background` property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Mozilla reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference) and the main section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS). These should provide you with a good "way in" and an explanation of the -moz-XXX prefix.